# Using old JavaScript files with webpack, what is the ES6 way?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, react-rails, webpacker

I have used the react-rails gem for a while. While using it, I placed my ES6 components under `app/assets/javascript/components` folder and placed plain old JavaScript files to `app/assets/javascript`. The good thing was I was able to easily refer the objects of old style Javascript files from the ES6 components.

After migrating to webpacker gem, I tried to keep similar approach. I placed the modules under `app/javascript/packs` and placed old style JavaScript files unde `app/javascript` folder.

I guess, with webpack in place I have to use import / export mechanics but that I could not achieved either.

So my question is how can I use old javascript files and refer the objects inside them, within components.

For example the content of a dummy `global_data.js` file that reside in `app/javascript` directory is as follows:

```
function globalData (){
}
globalData.prototype.data = {};
var g_GlobalData = new globalData();
```

What is the ES6 way to use `g_GlobalData` variable within components?

Comment: Export `g_GlobalData`?

Comment: Followed by `import g_GlobalData from 'path/to/g_GlobalData.js';` in the file you want to consume it with

Comment: evolutionxbox and @Ted, thanks this is the obvious thing to do. I had also done export and import previously but in that case the "data" attribute which was initiated at line 3 is not seen. That is why I thought something else could possibly be the solution. (Briefly, when I refer ```g_GlobalData.data```, I get "undefined" in export / import case.)

Comment: @MehmetKaplan Hard to say without seeing `g_GlobalData`. For instance, if `g_GlobalData.js` starts with `export const data = {...}`, `g_GlobalData.data` should be good, or if it's `const data = {...}; export default data;` then `g_GlobalData` refers to `data`. Make sense? What you export, and how, from `g_GlobalData` is key.

Comment: @Ted, makes a perfect sense, even it solved my problem pal. Thank you. For the brief, my export was ```module.exports = {g_GlobalData: g_GlobalData};``` Your comment made me understand actually I should have used ```module.exports = g_GlobalData;``` which I did and solved my problem. :-) Cheers!

Comment: @MehmetKaplan excellent! Glad you got it working.